# Merge date and time columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Currently I have 2 columns one that holds dates and the other holds the time (24hr text version).

Example:

```
a_dt          a_time_text
01-Jan-15     0224
31-Mar-15     0317
15-Sep-15     2010
```

How do I create a new column that hold the date and time, like this:

```
a_dt_tm
01-Jan-15 02:24
31-Mar-15 03:17
15-Sep-15 20:10
```

Or any other way so that I can find the difference in date/time between another variable.

Comment: Is there a a reason you currently have the time in a separate column? Perhaps whoever designed this didn't realised Oracle's DATE datatype includes the time?

Comment: I didn't gather the data or create the data set. I was just given the data to work with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this:

```
to_date
   ( to_char (a_dt,'YYYYMMDD')
        || a_time_text,
     'YYYYMMDDHH24MI'
   )
```

i.e. first convert the date column to a string - `to_char (a_dt,'YYYYMMDD')`, then append the time string, then convert the resulting string back to a date.

Comment: this only prints out the `DD-MMM-YYYY

Comment: @AmandaR. - this creates a DATE value. To display it as text in a specific format use `to_char()`, or change your client's NLS_DATE_FORMAT - in either case with a format model like `'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'`. You will probably see that the times in all your original `a_dt` values are 00:00:00

Comment: I'm using Oracle SQL